# How to get a list of words from a Full Text Search dictionary

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, full-text-search, postgresql-9.0

Is there a way to query a dictionary using SQL in PostgreSQL, to get a list of words in that dictionary? I'm using Postgres 9.0.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's being asked here. If you're asking whether there's a built-in dictionary in PostgreSQL, then no.

Comment: But there *is* some kind of built in dictionary in Postgres. It's used for the Full Text Search features. My question is, can I get access to the words in that dictionary with a query?

Comment: @BrianWillis: I disagree, the question is very clear.

Comment: In postgresql parlance, a dictionary is not a list of words: it's kind of a filtering program, as explained here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way I`m aware of, but assuming that You are using an aspell dictionary:

```
cat `pg_config --sharedir`/tsearch_data/english.dict |aspell -l en expand
```

Lists the words.